# Pygame window freezes when using threads

Tags: python, pygame, python-multithreading

I have a pygame script that starts up with a white screen and then transitions to a black screen when the user types something. The user input is handled by another thread and I used `queue.Queue` to pass messages from the input thread to the pygame one.

The problem is that whenever I run the script the pygame window will freeze after a short while. If I type in something quickly the screen will change from white to black but the window still freezes. I'm not sure where the script gets stuck?

```py
import pygame
import threading 
import queue

q = queue.Queue()

pygame.init()

#rgb codes 
black = (0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255)

game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 800))

def screen_1():

    crashed = False

    #holds messages from input thread
    msg = ''

    game_display.fill(white)

    while not crashed:

        #check if there are any messages in the queue
        try:
            msg = q.get(False)
        except queue.Empty:
            pass

        if msg:
            return screen_2()

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                crashed = True        

        pygame.display.update()

def screen_2():

    crashed = False

    game_display.fill(black)

    while not crashed:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                crashed = True

        pygame.display.update()        

def inputFunc():
    msg = input('Type something:\n')
    q.put(msg)

t1 = threading.Thread(target = screen_1)
t2 = threading.Thread(target = inputFunc)

t1.start()
t2.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I just figured out that running the pygame bit in a thread causes the window to freeze. If I only create a thread for `inputFunc` and call `screen_1` everything works just fine.